# Can a windows computer turn itself on/off automatically although it was switched off

Tags: windows-8, boot, automation

A colleague claims that his private computer with Windows 8 at home has synched bookmark information with his windows phone and downloaded Windows updates during his holiday although it was switched off completely.

He said, the WIFI was not switched off during the holiday but for testing he switched it off after coming back and *before* starting his computer.

Is it really possible (today) that a computer with Windows operating system automatically switches itself on, performs downloads or syncs and then switches itself off again?
This would have to be built in the operating system

Comment: The only thing I could think of with this is that they have Wake On LAN setup in the BIOS?  In terms of the phone sending a startup signal to the machine, I wouldn't think that was the case, unless they had some remote management tool(?)

Comment: @James: "itself" wouldn't work with Wake On LAN.

Answer (score 2):

Some BIOSes have a feature called "Power-On by alarm" where you can define the time to wake up the PC. Of course that implies the PC itself is powered.

[image: Power-On by Alarm]

You could then e.g. set up an automated login ([SysInternals AutoLogon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963905.aspx)) and perform any task, including shutdown. Another option is to install a Windows service that runs at boot time, so it executes at the login screen already.

Wake On LAN would require a second device which sends the magic packet to wake up the PC. However, such a thing could easily be implemented on a device like a NAS or a wireless router, so there needn't be another PC.

Comment: And when scheduling a task in Task Scheduler you can select "Wake the computer to run this task" to have the computer started automatically with the use of this BIOS feature.

Comment: @MBu: IMHO this Task Scheduler setting would only work if the computer is in Sleep mode, not if it's powered off.

Comment: You eventually should point out that most services, notably the update service, do not need any user to be logged on to shut down the system. Therefore, when restricting your answer to the OP's question, no automated login is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, it could be seen as that, yes.

The answer is no, if turned off is really off (start->shut down, shut down).

But if by turned off, you refer to the pc being in hibernation, and the pc is set to go to hibernation after a while of inactivity, then yes, it is possible if the pc is setup to wake up from lan activity.

If a pc is not even in hibernation but in sleep, then windows itself can schedule tasks to get a pc out of sleep to perform tasks.

So the answer depends on how relative you see "switched off".

But if you mean, that the computer is not in windows, then its unlikely.

Comment: Wake on Lan can start from a shutdown (power off state) if the BIOS has this setting enabled.

Comment: thanks - as I understood it, the PC was really switched off (no hibernation or sleep mode), but I'll ask again. Would "wake on LAN" also be possible with WiFi?

Comment: @MostlyHarmless: Wake on *W*LAN is possible with WiFi. Wake on LAN usually refers to wired LAN. More importantly practically any computer can wake at any arbitrary time Windows chooses to set. Often used for overnight maintenance, updates, etc.

Comment: To whoever voted me down, please explain why?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq: does Windows 8 have a default settings which lets the computer boot at night for downloading updates (and then shut down again)?

Comment: @MostlyHarmless: Not that I'm aware of, though previous versions of Windows did default to "Install updates at 3am". Even then, Windows would not log itself in unless you told it to so it would never sync your bookmarks.

Comment: I didn't vote you down (there is no reason to do that), but perhaps it happened because your answer is not completely correct. There are BIOSes which can wake up the PC after it has shutdown normally (i.e. not hibernating / sleeping). This is even possible by schedule; it does not need to happen by Wake-On-LAN.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me! But even more weird. I have two computers. One for gaming and one for media. The least powerful for media. All I do is switch Ethernet and HDMI between the two. I've had my gaming comp for several years, and it has never switched itself on for no reason, it's not even connected to the internet, as I was using the media one. It's windows 10, and it doesn't have a wireless card. It scared the life out of me! I was sat watching tv. after a few minutes, it just shut itself down! Weird.

Comment: You eventually should look into the configuration of Windows Update. With the default configuration, it will download and install updates and restart automatically. You can configure this, though. However, your post is not an answer to the OP's question. It is more a comment. If you write an answer, please provide a real answer, not further questions or a "mee, too".